# Linux Background Process to Foreground

Tags: java, unix, background-process

How can I view the status of  a background process that was created by using the "&" command? I ran a Java program using the "java program_name" command, and I just tacked on the "&" sign. The process went to the background, and the process ID number was generated. I have the process ID number, and I can see it as an active process when I use the "ps" command. However, I am not sure if the Java code needed more memory, and it threw an exception or something.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: If the process id shows up in "ps", then the process is still active. That means there wasn't an uncaught Exception or Error (which would have crashed the process). What else do you want to know, exactly?

Comment: Hey Adam, Thanks a lot! That is pretty much what I wanted to find out. I didn't this until you told me, and I was thinking that the process shows up as an active process even if an exception occurs. I am really sorry, I just started using UNIX and I guess I am posting really naive questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think  the safest way is to redirect stderr and stdout to a file and then look in there to see what happened.

```
java dave >results.txt 2>&1
```

More details [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redirecting-stderr-to-stdout/)

Comment: Much appreciated Dave! I will re-run it using the above command.